# Kuberenetes importing issue Python 3.6.8 on CentOS 7

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have been banging my head on the wall trying to get the following import to work.

`from kubernetes import config, client`

I pip installed kubernetes==11.0.0

It works perfectly fine on https://repl.it/languages/python3 but getting import error on my CentOS 7 box.
`from kubernetes import config, watch, client`
`ImportError: cannot import name 'config'`

I have been using Python for 7-8 years, I am not sure what I am missing.

Thanks!

Comment: `import(kubernetes); dir(kubernetes)`... Do you see a config module there?

Answer (score 1):

Found my issue, file name was `kubernetes.py`. Renamed it and solved issue :|.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you name your file kubernetes.py, the import is attempted from that particular file than from the library

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).